# How do I make Weblogic 10 prefer the jars in myApp.war:/WEB-INF/lib/ without throwing VerifyErrors?

Tags: java, weblogic, classloader, web-inf

The Weblogic classloader seems to prefer system libraries over the libraries in my war's `WEB-INF/lib/`.

I've tried setting the following in `WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`, without success:

```
<weblogic-web-app>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

This just gives me a lot of VerifyErrors:

```
exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractSAXParser, method: parse signature: (Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;)V) Incompatible object argument for function call
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

(I'm trying to avoid packaging the WAR into an EAR.)

Comment: What system libraries are these?

Comment: prefer-web-inf-classes should work, I assume you've cleared out all temp folders and cached copies of the war within the domain?

Comment: Is this to do with the JAXP libraries that Weblogic helpfully includes in your war's classpath?

Comment: There is a new option in WebLogic to use the perfer-application-packages in WAR files.  What version are you using?

Comment: @Jeff West: We use 11g.  Which option is that?

Comment: @artbristol: It looks like Weblogic have already loaded Sax components into the classpath, which crashes with differently versioned Sax in the War.

Comment: WebLogic enables you to do bottoms-up classloading which loads from the WAR/EAR first, getting around the clashes.

Comment: 11g has multiple releases.  Are you using 10.3.3 or 10.3.4, perhaps?

Comment: If you want to continue the conversation, email me at jeffrey.west@oracle.com.  Easier than message board for iterative work.  We can post the result here.

Answer (score 5):

I was never able to fix this satisfactorily, other than by specifying `-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=[xerces sax parser factory class name]` (and so on for the other JAXP factories like validation SchemaFactory) when starting Weblogic.

None of the filtering / `prefer-web-inf` stuff worked, possibly due to Weblogic requiring JAXP libraries on startup before it even reads any of the WAR / EAR config files.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too with tomcat-arquillian. Turns out "xml-apis 2.0.2" was in my classpath, which is actually xml-apis 1.0.b2 and which is too old to be compatible with xercesImpl 2.9.1 which requires xml-apis 1.3.04.